# Realizar una query mediante un select en HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, select

Muy buenas, estoy intentando realizar una query mediante la opción seleccionada en select de HTML, al cual le puse de nombre "filtro", creo las opciones dinamicas y con un switch obtengo lo seleccionado. El caso es que a partir de ahí estoy atorado no se donde colocar la el código que me carga los resultados y tal.
Les muestro el codigo a continuación:

```
<form name = "filtro"><select>
        <option value = "seleccionar">Seleccionar categoria</option>
        <option value = "centrosdeent">Centros de entretenimiento</option>
        <option value = "cocinas">Cocinas</option>
        <option value = "comedores">Comedores</option>
        <option value = "decoracion">Decoración</option>
        <option value = "recamaras">Recamaras</option>
        <option value = salas>Salas</option>
    </select></form><br>
    <?php
    switch ($_POST['filtro']){
        case 'seleccionar':
            $q = "SELECT * FROM muebles";
            $rs = mysql_query($q);
            break;
        case 'centrosdeent':
            $q = "SELECT centrosdeent FROM muebles";
            $rs = mysql_query($q);
            break;
        case 'cocinas':
            $q = "SELECT cocinas FROM muebles";
            $rs = mysql_query($q);
            break;
        case 'comedores':
            $q = "SELECT comedores FROM muebles";
            $rs = mysql_query($q);
            break;
        case 'decoracion':
            $q = "SELECT decoracion FROM muebles";
            $rs = mysql_query($q);
            break;
        case 'recamaras':
            $q = "SELECT recamaras FROM muebles";
            $rs = mysql_query($q);
            break;
        case 'salas':
            $q = "SELECT sala FROM muebles";
            $rs = mysql_query($q);
            break;
        default:
            $q = "SELECT * FROM muebles";
            $rs = mysql_query($q);
            break;
    }
    while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
        echo "<b>Nombre:</b> $fila[nom]<br>";
        echo "<b>Modelo:</b> $fila[modelo]<br>";
        echo "<b>Categoria:</b> $fila[cat]<br>";
        echo "<b>Sub Categoria:</b> $fila[subcat]<br>";
        echo "<b>Precio:</b> $fila[pre]<br><br>";}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta deberías realizarlo de la siguiente manera :

```
<?php 
 if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){
    switch ($_POST['filtro']){
        case 'seleccionar':
            $q = "SELECT * FROM muebles";
            $rs = mysql_query($q);
            break;
        case 'centrosdeent':
            $q = "SELECT centrosdeent FROM muebles";
            $rs = mysql_query($q);
            break;
        case 'cocinas':
            $q = "SELECT cocinas FROM muebles";
            $rs = mysql_query($q);
            break;
        case 'comedores':
            $q = "SELECT comedores FROM muebles";
            $rs = mysql_query($q);
            break;
        case 'decoracion':
            $q = "SELECT decoracion FROM muebles";
            $rs = mysql_query($q);
            break;
        case 'recamaras':
            $q = "SELECT recamaras FROM muebles";
            $rs = mysql_query($q);
            break;
        case 'salas':
            $q = "SELECT sala FROM muebles";
            $rs = mysql_query($q);
            break;
        default:
            $q = "SELECT * FROM muebles";
            $rs = mysql_query($q);
            break;
    }
    while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
        echo "<b>Nombre:</b> $fila[nom]<br>";
        echo "<b>Modelo:</b> $fila[modelo]<br>";
        echo "<b>Categoria:</b> $fila[cat]<br>";
        echo "<b>Sub Categoria:</b> $fila[subcat]<br>";
        echo "<b>Precio:</b> $fila[pre]<br><br>";}

 }else{
     //Agregamos action='<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>' para que se recargue la página y realice la consulta
    ?>
    <form  action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
       <select name="filtro">
            <option value = "seleccionar">Seleccionar categoria</option>
            <option value = "centrosdeent">Centros de entretenimiento</option>
            <option value = "cocinas">Cocinas</option>
            <option value = "comedores">Comedores</option>
            <option value = "decoracion">Decoración</option>
            <option value = "recamaras">Recamaras</option>
            <option value = salas>Salas</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Consultar" name="enviar">
    </form>
    <br>
    <?php
     }

?>
```

Aunque yo te recomiendo cambiar a mysqli antes de que avances más tu proyecto, MySqli es la nueva librería de php para consulta ya que mysql quedo obsoleta y es insegura en comparación de esta. ¿te funciono?

Comment: Hola, me ha funcionado... en parte, te explico:  
En primer lugar quería que solo al dar clic en la opción se recargara la página, creo que tengo que vivir con eso.  
En segundo lugar, cuando selecciono una opción y le doy al botón, me realiza la busqueda en general, es decir "SELECT * FROM muebles".  
Por ultimo, quisiera que me explicaras por que es mejor mysqli.  
Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: mysql ya quedo obsoleto, en php 7 y te dara advertencias de uso en php 5.6+ , es más seguro y te permitirá tener más seguridad en tus consultas, agrega al select el nombre, se me paso, lo estoy agregando

Comment: ya te debería de funcionar :)

Comment: Buena respuesta. Pero habría que agregarle al combo `<select>` el manejador de `onchange=""`, para que envíe el formulario sin presionar el botón de Enviar (en ese caso, en vez de preguntar por  `isset($_POST["enviar"])`, que pregunte por `isset($_POST["filtro"]) && !empty($_POST["filtro"])` ).

Comment: Probe con el metodo de quinqui, y me dio este error:  
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'isset' (T_ISSET), expecting '(' in C:\AppServ\www\Redwood\catalogo.php on line 9`  
Y el arreglo de Christopher Villa me ha dado este:  
`Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\AppServ\www\Redwood\catalogo.php on line 44`
Creanme, antes de comentar he revisado muchisimas veces como solucionarlo, pero no logro corregirlo. Creo que me pondré a leer un curso completo de PHP. Muchas gracias por sus respuestas chicos.